# Can't find my Node-RED code for GIT

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm trying to make some changes to my Node-RED bluemix-settings.js file and I'm having trouble finding it where I can edit it. I see this:

[image]

If I look at the Files, I see this:

[image]

Is there something that I can do that will "connect" these two so that I can make changes?

Comment: Did you leave the "Add Sample app code" box ticked when you added the git repo?

Comment: I believe the node-red code is stored in your Cloudant service.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you created the IBM DevOps Services repository starting from your Bluemix Node-RED application and clicking the button that allows to add Git integration. Looking at your screenshots it is clear that your repo has not been populated with the starter code of your Node-RED application. That's the reason why you see the .js file on Bluemix and not in the repo.
This can happen if (as already suggested) you don't select the checkbox *Populate the repo with the starter app package and enable the Build & Deploy pipeline*, or it can also depend on an issue in the Bluemix-IDS Delivery Pipeline integration.

Anyway you could fix this downloading the starter code again from the *Getting Started* tab in your Bluemix application dashboard and uploading it manually to the repository in the *Edit Code* tab (*File->Import*).
Doing that you will be able to edit, commit and push the changes directly on Bluemix from the IDS Web IDE.